# call get Adapter Position error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQofG.png)so, when I write position on  43rd line, int position on 40th line should change into final int position, but it doesn't. so I think I have to use getAdapterPosition() instead, inside bind view holder method. but I don't know how? can anyone help me? thanks in advance!

I tried to change int position into final int position manually let's say by myself tho didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the getAdapterPosition() on your holder instead of the position and the lint should go away. Documentation states:

> RecyclerView will not call this method again if the position of the
> item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or
> the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should
> only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item
> inside this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the
> position of an item later on (e.g. in a click listener), use
> getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adapter position.

Have a look here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder%28VH,%20int%29

Comment: you mean on line 49, instead of position write - holder.getAdapterPosition() right?

Comment: everywhere you have used the position parameter, yes